# Got "No provider Exception" putting ngControl for sub-component

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to implement custom form using Angular2 (with TypeScript and Jade).

When I used `my-input` element I created as custom form components instead of `input` and added `ngControl` directive to `input`, I got exception errors "No provider for ControlContainer!". Then, when I removed `ngControl` from `input` element, errors didn't occur but the form functions didn't work (e.g. validators).

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'top-page',
  template: `
    <form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
      <my-input name="username" placeholder="username is here.">
    </form>
  `,
});
export class TopPageComponent { ... }
```

**Sub-Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
    <label class="custom-class-1">
      <div class="custom-class-2"></div>
      <input type="text" id="{{name}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ngControl="{{name}}" [(ngModel)]="{{name}}">
    </label>
  `,
});
export class MyInputComponent { ... }
```

For trial, I append `ngControlGroup` directive to `label` element in `my-input` component, but getting errors.
(Of course, wrote `import Component, Input, etc...` and `@Input()` in TypeScript files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should put a form tag into your sub component:

```
<form>
  <label class="custom-class-1">
    <div class="custom-class-2"></div>
      <input type="text" id="{{name}}"
             placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
             ngControl="{{name}}" [(ngModel)]="{{name}}">
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: It depend on what you want to do. Your sub component can't participate out of the box to the form of the parent component. There is a bit work to do ;-) See this link for more details: http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/. In the section "NgModel-compatible component"